# How to return value from lambda expression? (JavaFx- ChoiceBox addListener)

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

```
choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener( (v, oldValue, newValue) -> {selectedColor = newValue.toString();});

System.out.println(selectedColor);
```

I want to pass the newValue to selectedColor but outside the lambda it's not printing anything.

Comment: you can put that print statement in a method and call that mehod inside lambda . it don't print anything  'cause that statement will not update itself

Comment: `System.out.println(selectedColor);`  will not update itself , even if `selectedColor`  variable changes

Comment: I would suggest that you replace all `selectedColor` variables with `choiceBox.getValue()`. If you continue to have a problem after that, post an MCVE.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re trying to do. `choiceBox.getValue()` will always give you the currently selected value from the choice box. There’s no need to create another variable (`selectedValue`) to store it. If you need to do something when it changes just include the “do something” in the lambda expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you provide more details on what you want to accomplish i can only guess what would help you. But the following code would make your example work the way you describe it:

```
choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((v,oldValue,newValue) -> {
printSelection(newValue.toString());
});


private void printSelection(String selection){
    System.out.println(selection);
    //Here you can do what ever you need to do with the given value of 'selection'
}
```

For a better solution you need to provide more Details on what your goal is, what you want to use the `newValue` for